# how to count the number of last day

Tags: sql, oracle

I  got a data like it :

```
id   date_       type

1   05/03/2020   A

2   07/03/2020   A
3   15/03/2020   A
4   25/03/2020   B
5   24/03/2020   B
6  31/03/2020   C
7   31/03/2020   D
```

I used the function last_day,

I did it :

```
select last_day(date_) from table1
```

But I got it :

```
31/03/2020 :  7
```

And I want to have it :

```
31/03/2020 : 2
```

thanks !

Comment: Just as a side observation, I'm not a fan of simply adding an underscore to what is really a reserved word, just to make it not a reserved word.  Why not give 'DATE_'  (and _all_ of your columns) a meaningful, self-documenting name that actually indicates to others what the data actually is?  Something like ORDER_DATE, or INVOICE_DATE.  All of my columns are in the format ADJECTIVE_NOUN.  Makes it much easier to understand exactly what you are dealing with when writing/maintaining code.  And you should be commended for using 4-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the count of records having last day of the month in date_ field then:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table1(id int,  date_ date,       type varchar(10));

 insert into table1 values(1,   '05-Mar-2020',   'A');
 insert into table1 values(2,   '07-Mar-2020',   'A');
 insert into table1 values(3,   '15-Mar-2020',   'A');
 insert into table1 values(4,   '25-Mar-2020',   'B');
 insert into table1 values(5,   '24-Mar-2020',   'B');
 insert into table1 values(6,   '31-Mar-2020',   'C');
 insert into table1 values(7,   '31-Mar-2020',   'D');
```

Query:

```
 select date_, count(*)cnt
 from table1
 where date_ = last_day(date_)
 group by date_;
```

Ouput:

| DATE_ | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| 31-MAR-20 | 2 |

If you need all the date_ with count no need to use last_day:

Query:

```
select date_, count(*)cnt
 from table1
 group by date_
 order by date_;
```

Output:

| DATE_ | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| 05-MAR-20 | 1 |
| 07-MAR-20 | 1 |
| 15-MAR-20 | 1 |
| 24-MAR-20 | 1 |
| 25-MAR-20 | 1 |
| 31-MAR-20 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=122a76f3338050caaa9f4a16e77bf0ea)*

Comment: thanks for answer,  but how can I have other information ?,

Comment: so how can I have the number of other date_ ?

Comment: @seb do you need all the date_ with count?

Comment: yes exactely,  I need type and other date_

Comment: I have revised my answer. If it's not what you are looking for then please share your desired output from the sample provided.

Comment: yes but you don't have the type associated of every date

Comment: You need type wise date wise count? there are two types for 31/03/2020: C and D. What will be the output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select date_, count(*)
from t
where date_ = last_day(date_)
group by date_;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it, "last day" isn't the result of the `LAST_DAY` function, but maximum date value in that table. The result you're after is count of rows whose date is equal to that "maximum" date.

If that's so, then this might be one option: counting rows is easy. `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function calculates ordinal numbers of each row, sorted by date in descending order which means that it is the 1st row you need.

Something like this:

```
SQL> select date_, cnt
  2  from (select date_,
  3          count(*) cnt,
  4          row_number() over (order by date_ desc) rn
  5        from table1
  6        group by date_
  7       )
  8  where rn = 1;

DATE_             CNT
---------- ----------
31/03/2020          2

SQL>
```